# Print directly to network printer using php

Tags: php, windows, printing, network-printers

I am unable to print a page to a network printrer using php.
But this works if it is a local printer.
I have installed php_printer.dll and enabled in php.ini 
The following is the code:

```
//$handle  =  printer_open("Send To OneNote 2007"); ///This Works

$handle = printer_open('\\\\192.168.0.8\\Canon MF4320-4350'); 
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
printer_write($handle, "TEXT To print");
printer_close($handle);
```

It shows the error

> Warning: printer_write() [function.printer-write]: couldn't allocate the 
>       printerjob [5] in E:\Server\xampp\htdocs\Kiosk\Admin\print.php on line 16

Answer (score 7):

If you used the command line PHP (CLI) the printing to network printers would work. Your $addr is correct by the way.

The issue lies with PHP when you combine it with Apache. In windows, your php scripts would run under the user SYSTEM. Because of security concerns, all network resources are not visible to SYSTEM.

To resolve this problem, create a new user with admin privileges (or at least with Network Resource visibility). In Windows, if you run Apache as a service, click on the SERVICE button in the Apache Service Monitor. Under Apache 2.2, right click on properties. Under the LOGIN tab, change the user from SYSTEM to your newly created user account. Restart Apache. You should be able to run your PHP script to print to network printers now.

Answer (score 1):

Try using either "s with 4\ or 's with 3. eg:

```
$handle = printer_open("\\\\192.168.0.8\\Canon MF4320-4350");
// or
$handle = printer_open('\\\192.168.0.8\Canon MF4320-4350');
```

Also, try using a domain name rather than IP (eg. `computer-name` or `full.address.example.com`).

Comment: Tried all ways, but of no use.Thanks for your response

Comment: Hmm, that's odd because the comments on the php.net manual page seem to suggest that it works correctly with those methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at that string, it feels very much as if it's likely to be caused by back-slash escaping going wrong.

Debugging tip: Set your network address in a variable rather than directly in `printer_open()`. Then use `print()` or similar to display the value.

```
<?php
   $addr = '\\\\192.168.0.8\\Canon MF4320-4350';
   print $addr;
   printer_open($addr);
   ...
?>
```

This will allow you to see the value of the string that you're using, which might help you see what's going wrong, and more importantly, help you see how to fix it.

Hope that helps.