# Printing data to printer using PHP

Tags: php, windows, printing

I have a question that has been troubling me for at least 3 weeks now. I need to print some data to a printer using php. I have data saved into a `$print_output` variable, and I know my data is good because when I send it via email, it shows everything that is supposed to  be shown.

Well, I tried writing this code, where I thought I could test it but wasn't sure if it would have even worked.

```
$handle = printer_open("\\\\192.168.1.33_4\\Printer_Office");
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "raw"); 
printer_write($handle,$print_output); 
printer_close($handle);
```

Well, turns out I don't have php_printer.dll extension installed and I was told not to re-compile php to add it.

What I'd like to do is simply print out the data that is stored in `$print_output` to a printer on my same network. I don't want to use the javascript function `window.print()` because I can't have a print dialogue screen pop up.

Does anyone have any information that can point me in the right direction? Or another way to simply print a small amount of data directly to the printer without using php's `printer_open` function?

Comment: I think you could handle it via plain socket programming. It really depends on your printer. An example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16689282/1948627

Comment: Thank you, I am being forced to use php 5.2.0 :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For anyone who is having the same trouble, I figured out I can simply push the data using socket programming as follows. The ip address below is my printer's ip address. You can telnet into your printer to make sure the connection works beforehand if you'd like.

```
if(isset($_POST['order'])){
$print_output= $_POST['order'];
}
try
{
    $fp=pfsockopen("192.168.1.33", 9100);
    fputs($fp, $print_output);
    fclose($fp);

    echo 'Successfully Printed';
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: one of the best features PHP offered, now they are unsupported. Now gone.

Comment: @HenryW I just looked it up in the manual, doesn't say anything about deprecation... Am I missing something??

Answer (score 6):

You have several options to print with PHP on Windows:

#### 1. Extension "php_printer"

Because PHP 5.2.0 is outdated, it's quite hard to find compiled extension.
 You might try to drop in the php_printer extension for 5.2.8:

http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_printer-cvs-20081215-5.2.8-nts-Win32.zip

Add to your php.ini:

```
extension=php_printer.dll
```

Recent version might be found at Pierre's download site: http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

#### 2. Execute the windows CLI command "print" via PHP

An alternative solution is to use the windows command "print".

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772773%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

```
exec("print /d:\\192.168.1.33_4\\Printer_Office c:\accounting\report.txt);
```

#### 3. Use Sockets

```
$fp=pfsockopen("192.168.1.201",9100);
fputs($fp,$print_data);
fclose($fp);
```

#### 4. Output to HTML, open in browser and trigger window.print()

Comment: I had already tried that and edited the php.ini, but it still says the function is undefined. Thank you, though.

Comment: Ok. An alternative solution is to use the windows command "print" (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772773%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). Example: exec("print /d:\\192.168.1.33_4\\Printer_Office c:\accounting\report.txt);

Comment: How to make this works with USB printer ..

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
I found that I can use mike42 escpos github plugin.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\CapabilityProfile;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;


$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("smb://computername/printername");
$printer = new Printer($connector);

$printer -> text("hello world");
$printer -> text("\n");
$printer -> text("\n");
$printer -> text("hello again");
$printer -> cut();
$printer -> close();
```

Comment: I tried it bu unfortunately  it didn't work with (Arabic scripting )