# Is there a way in PHP to store printjobs that are sent via a Windows PC?

Tags: php, printing

I am working on a project for school. I am wondering if there is a way in PHP to listen for print jobs and store them once received? I currently have a webserver that is accepting webhooks from other applications, parsing out the JSON and storing in a MsSQL. Is this the wrong path to take? thanks

Comment: Are you interfacing with the printer via a webpage or directly from php? Based on your comments - it appears you are directly interfacing with a printer from your box - in which case depending on your set up, you can use LPR or if you are on Windows you can use LPT2. Alternatively you can use this method somebody on SO has used: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313439/printing-data-to-printer-using-php

Comment: I am trying to basically write a PHP script on my local webserver. I would print to this IP and the php script would be my index of the webserver. I want to take the print object and store it. Kindof like a print queue. At this point I just want to store it or covert to a PDF. Do not need to send to a printer or anything. I have a later project to grab the data that is being stored by another app and print it to a printer. One thing at a time haha

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Can I ask what your use case is - or what are you trying to achieve (this is for my personal curiosity). Your approach would work if the incoming data is json format everytime. If not (and if possible) I would essentially output the incoming files to a folder (with the correct permissions etc) and then print the documents in this folder as required. You could also build a quick interface to see what docs are present there etc. Again - all this is possible with your approach as well.

Comment: Basically want trying to solve a problem for printing from remote. Store all print jobs and then fetch them when I'm on a device I can actually print from. Weird idea but it's apart of a larger project.

Comment: That being said a default print job is not in json format so I'm unsure how to accept and store the object a Windows PC is going to send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok – I don’t know if this is a solution but here is my attempt at trying to help :)

Disclaimer: I am not affiliated to any of the links posted here and (or) make no recommendations.

**General assumptions:**

1. PHP is the server side language used in all instances (the theory should work with others as well – using PHP as the question was tagged as such)
2. Sender and receiver servers are different (it is more easier if both are on the same box – but not a show stopper)
3. Access to both sender and receiver webservers
4. Windows set up (WAMP or alternative)
5. You are securing your set up / directory accesses as you go along

**Option 1 (Custom sender / receiver)**

On the box that is sending the print request:

- Create a PHP script to output the files to a temp directory
- Create file with required extension (please see documentation if required)
- Put contents
- Close connection / file - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php
- Use powershell or alternative to put the files in the temp directory into a remote directory on the
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/luisdem/2016/08/31/powershell-how-to-copy-a-local-file-to-remote-machines/
- Run this at an interval of your choice

**On the box that is receiving the file:**

- Create a PHP script to read files on remote
- Show files to print in a list which can be downloaded to local terminal / device and printed

**Option 2 (Leverage an existing print server)**

In this option you would only need to amend the sender webserver config:
[inspired by: https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/printing-directly-php]

- Download php_printer.dll for your version (https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/printer/0.1.0-dev/)
- Enable in php.ini via: printer.default_printer=PHP_INI_ALL extension=php_printer.dll
- Set the printer as your print server address and send your output to print directly from the Webserver as follows from your application:

  `
     $data= "Hello";
     printer_set_option($ph, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
     printer_write($ph, $data);
    printer_close($ph);
  }
   else "Couldn't connect...";
  ?>'

**Option 3 (Use a plugin):**
https://www.neodynamic.com/products/printing/raw-data/php/