# print directly from iis using php aplication to printer through server not browser to a shared printer

Tags: php, iis, printing

I have programmed an application on iis with PHP language.
this app is food reservation.
this app must  get  data from a face reader device then send print to a thermal printer.
this app can get data from face reader device but my problem is when I want to send print to printer that is shared I can't achieve.
in fact I want to send a text file using php and iis to a shared printer **(not through browser)** and I want to ask you what is the solution?

I have read many articles but I couldn't achieve up to now.
please notice that I  want to send print using php and **not using browser**.
and it must be send using php to printer directly.

system specifications:

IIS v 8.5

PHP v 5.6.31

windows server 2012 r2

I have tested bellow codes and I had problem as below:

**1-sending print directly to printer through excec function:**

```
exec(' notepad /PT "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\goodtest.txt" "\\\192.168.10.21\BIX"')
```

problem is when I use this method I can't send print in windows server 2012 r2.

**2- sending through bat file:**
a bat file include these codes:

```
 notepad /P "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\goodtest.txt"
```

and a php file includethese codes:

```
system("cmd /c c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\d.bat");
```

the code doesn't work.

**3- sending through print php extension that doesn't work.**

so please guide me how I can send a print directly to printer using php and iis **not through a browser** to **a shared printer**.

some answers explains about network printer but **I ask about shared printer not a network printer.**
thanks a lot.

Comment: I've seen these but never try one of them before. http://www.nusphere.com/kb/phpmanual/ref.printer.htm (use PECL) or https://www.neodynamic.com/products/printing/raw-data/php/ or maybe search for raw print

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing data to printer using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313439/printing-data-to-printer-using-php)

Comment: @LexLi  that is not my answer. I have a shared printer not a network printer.

Comment: @vee I am testing https://www.neodynamic.com/products/printing/raw-data/php/ right now I will write its result here

Comment: @vee I have tested neodynamic.com/products/printing/raw-data/php please tell me can I send a print to printer using php or I must use javascript and opening web browser to print?

Comment: @rezaSefiddashti I've never try one of them before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after 4 weeks I find a solution.
this is a way to use a shared printer.
use mike42 escpos github plugin.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\CapabilityProfile;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;


$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("smb://computername/printername");
$printer = new Printer($connector);

$printer -> text("hello world");
$printer -> text("\n");
$printer -> text("\n");
$printer -> text("hello again");
$printer -> cut();
$printer -> close();
```