# Print .zpl file

Tags: php, zpl

I'm creating a program in PHP to print a `.zpl` file, I would like to know if anyone knows which command can I use to print?
Because I've done the whole program, it's just not printing.

```
    echo "<script>alert('CODIGO INSERIDO');</script>";
    $l1 = 'CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~';
    $l2 = '^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTD^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR4,4~SD15^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ';
    $l3 = '^XA';
    $l4 = '^MMT';
    $l5 = '^PW900';
    $l6 = '^LL0600';
    $l7 = '^LS0';
    $l8 = '^FT34,536^A0N,74,50^FH\^FD'; //QTD1
    $l88 = '^FS';
    $l9 = '^FT34,425^A0N,74,50^FH\^FD'; //QTD2
    $l99 = '^FS';
    $l10 = '^FT34,314^A0N,74,50^FH\^FD'; //QTD 3
    $l100 = '^FS';
    $l11 = '^FT177,536^A0N,74,48^FH\^FD'; //COD1
    $l111 = '^FS';
    $l12 = '^BY4,2,76^FT420,537^BEN,,Y,N';
    $l13 = '^FD'; //BARRA1
    $l133 = '^FS';
    $l14 = '^FT33,201^A0N,74,50^FH\^FD'; //QTD4
    $l144 = '^FS';
    $l15 = '^FT177,425^A0N,74,48^FH\^FD'; //COD2
    $l155 = '^FS';
    $l16 = '^BY4,2,76^FT420,426^BEN,,Y,N';
    $l17 = '^FD'; //BARRA2
    $l177 = '^FS';
    $l18 = '^FT364,89^A0N,74,48^FH\^FD'; //NF N
    $l188 = '^FS';
    $l19 = '^FT177,314^A0N,74,48^FH\^FD'; //COD3
    $l199 = '^FS';
    $l20 = '^BY4,2,76^FT420,315^BEN,,Y,N';
    $l21 = '^FD'; //BARRA3
    $l211 = '^FS';
    $l22 = '^FT281,90^A0N,74,48^FH\^FD'; //NF
    $l222 = '^FS';
    $l23 = '^FT175,202^A0N,74,48^FH\^FD'; //COD4
    $l233 = '^FS';
    $l24 = '^BY4,2,76^FT418,202^BEN,,Y,N';
    $l25 = '^FD'; //BARRA4
    $l255 = '^FS';
    $l26 = '^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ';
    $arquivo = fopen('etiqueta.zpl', 'w');
    fwrite($arquivo, $l1);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l2);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l3);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l4);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l5);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l6);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l7);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l8);
    fwrite($arquivo, $qtd1);
    fwrite($arquivo, $l88);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l9);
    fwrite($arquivo, $qtd2);
    fwrite($arquivo, $l99);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l10);
    fwrite($arquivo, $qtd3);
    fwrite($arquivo, $l100);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l11);
    fwrite($arquivo, $cod1);
    fwrite($arquivo, $l111);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l12);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l13);
    fwrite($arquivo, $result1[BARRA]);
    fwrite($arquivo, $l133);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l14);
    fwrite($arquivo, $qtd4);
    fwrite($arquivo, $l144);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l15);
    fwrite($arquivo, $cod2);
    fwrite($arquivo, $l155);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l16);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l17);
    fwrite($arquivo, $result2[BARRA]);
    fwrite($arquivo, $l177);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l18);
    fwrite($arquivo, $nf);
    fwrite($arquivo, $l188);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l19);
    fwrite($arquivo, $cod3);
    fwrite($arquivo, $l199);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l20);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l21);
    fwrite($arquivo, $result3[BARRA]);
    fwrite($arquivo, $l211);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l22);
    fwrite($arquivo, "NF");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l222);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l23);
    fwrite($arquivo, $cod4);
    fwrite($arquivo, $l233);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l24);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l25);
    fwrite($arquivo, $result4[BARRA]);
    fwrite($arquivo, $l255);
    fwrite($arquivo,"\n");
    fwrite($arquivo, $l26);     
    fclose($arquivo);
    $_SESSION['PrintBuffer']=$arquivo;
    $handle = printer_open("CPD");
    //printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
    //print $_SESSION['PrintBuffer'];
    printer_write($handle, $_SESSION['PrintBuffer']);
    printer_close($handle);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? eg: reading the file with `file_get_contents`?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864065/print-to-zebra-printer-in-php

Comment: There are at least two different file formats that use .zpl as an extension: Microsoft Zune and Zebra Programming Language for label printers. Which one are you trying to work with? Please [edit] the question to include the portion of code where you've assembled what you want to print.

Comment: Are you printing locally or through TCP/IP?

Comment: I include the code :)

Comment: I'm priting locally

Comment: When I send this file to the printer, it returns the following message: Resource id #4

Comment: Try doing something less complex; printing a simple label and see if you can get that to work first. Seems weird to me that you're using a variable for each line anyway. Wouldn't printing locally be local to the server processing the PHP? Which would be the webserver in some data center/cloud? Have you found: https://www.neodynamic.com/articles/How-to-print-raw-Zebra-ZPL-commands-from-Javascript/