# How to open printer connection using an IP address?

Tags: php, printing

```
<?php

$fh = fopen($file_name.".pdf", "rb");
$content = fread($fh, filesize($file_name.".pdf"));
fclose($fh);

**$handle = printer_open("192.168.1.252\\Deskjet-D2600-series");**

printer_set_option($handle,PRINTER_MODE,"raw");
printer_write($handle,$content);
printer_close($handle);

?>
```

I am unable to connect to an IP printer. Please give me the solution to solve the problem.

Comment: And how are we supposed to help you if you don't even provide an error message?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printer-open.php comments suggest you can also use fsockopen()

Comment: if i run this page i don't get any error message. pls help me.

Comment: how i get the error message to see this problem.

Comment: any other menthod to connect printer mr. Till Helge helwig

Comment: Have you tried `$handle = printer_open("\\\\192.168.1.252\\Deskjet-D2600-series");` ?

Comment: yes i tried this method also.....

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9669033/1516112 ?